Magento 2 : setup:di:compile fails after upgrade
I have upgraded Magento from 2.4.5 to 2.4.7 and it went well.
Here are my system details
Composer version 2.7.6 

PHP version 8.2.12

Here are the steps I followed.

cp composer.json composer.json.bak && cp composer.lock
composer.lock.bak
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~2.0 --no-update
composer require-commerce  magento/product-community-edition=2.4.7
--no-update

updated composer files section as mentioned below from https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.7/composer.json
"psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
        }


 "require-dev": {
             "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "^2",
             "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7 || ^1.0",
             "dg/bypass-finals": "^1.4",
             "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.22",
             "lusitanian/oauth": "^0.8",
             "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
             "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^4.7",
             "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
             "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.12",
             "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.9",
             "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
             "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0",
             "symfony/finder": "^6.4"
         },
    


"autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    }, 


composer update
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Here is the error
There is an error in /home/public_html/setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/LazyControllerAbstractFactory.php at line: 78
Interface "Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface" not found#0 /home/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(136): require_once()
#1 /home/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#2 /home/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#3 /home/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php(100): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#4 /home/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php(69): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\ApplicationCodeGenerator->getFiles()
#5 /home/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\ApplicationCodeGenerator->doOperation()
#6 /home/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(209): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#7 /home/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(326): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#8 /home/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1078): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#9 /home/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(324): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#10 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(118): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#11 /home/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(175): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#12 /home/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#13 {main}


The issue was resolved by replacing setup folder from https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/setup to the base folder of Magento installation.

Magento removred zend framework from the magento version 2.4.6 and Replaced Zend_Filter with laminas/laminas-filter. for more details read below refrence link Magento Open Source 2.4.6 release notes
Also Check this one  https://www.magetop.com/blog/how-to-fix-class-zend-not-found-in-magento-2/

@ishaq
Hey,
Please follow the given steps,

Clear Generated Files and Cache
Check PHP Version Compatibility
Verify Composer Dependencies
Disable Third-Party Module.
Check for Conflicting Classes or Plugins

Thank You!
